# How can I check if object of JSON array contains number with certain name in Android Java?

Tags: java, android, json

I have this JSON array and I need to check every object of it if it has a "rain" number as 1st object does. How can I implement it in Java, Android?
I am making an android app that needs to analyze if it rains someday.

```
 "daily": [
        {
            "dt": 1597730400,
            "sunrise": 1597705822,
            "sunset": 1597758442,
            "temp": {
                "day": 299.15,
                "min": 288.84,
                "max": 299.15,
                "night": 288.84,
                "eve": 298.91,
                "morn": 299.15
            },
            "feels_like": {
                "day": 291.47,
                "night": 287.34,
                "eve": 293.53,
                "morn": 291.47
            },
            "pressure": 997,
            "humidity": 27,
            "dew_point": 278.72,
            "wind_speed": 9.52,
            "wind_deg": 200,
            "weather": [
                {
                    "id": 500,
                    "main": "Rain",
                    "description": "light rain",
                    "icon": "10d"
                }
            ],
            "clouds": 100,
            "pop": 0.86,
            "rain": 1.03,
            "uvi": 4.86
        }
```

Comment: Please update the question with a valid json and format it. Also, do show us the code you have tried so far.

Comment: Updated the post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
String yourJSONString; //should hold the JSON you have 
JSONArray c = JSONArray(yourJSONString);
    for (int i = 0 ; i < c.length(); i++) {
        JSONObject obj = c.getJSONObject(i);
        if(obj.has("rain")){
          //object has "rain" property
        }
        else{
          //object doesnt have "rain" property
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for your help, I cnhanged your code a little but I got the problem. The length of an array is 8 but LogCat shows only 2 messages. What I made wrong? See the screenshot https://imgur.com/a/QwM3Xfp

Comment: This is very weird. Check if you're getting an exception.

Comment: Also, post your entire JSON array, are you sure its length is 8?

Comment: I figured it out. Log cat shows 2020-08-19 16:59:29.653 10012-10012/com.example.carweather I/MyResult: Doesn't rain
2020-08-19 16:59:29.653 10012-10012/com.example.carweather I/chatty: uid=10305(com.example.carweather) identical 6 lines
2020-08-19 16:59:29.653 10012-10012/com.example.carweather I/MyResult: Doesn't rain. The problem is "identical 6 lines". The compiler just makes all the "Doesn't rain to this.

Comment: And here is the result for my town with more rainy weather https://imgur.com/a/Zk2OO7C  thank you again!

Comment: Glad i could help! please accept the answer so other people can find it

Comment: Could you please help me on this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63643994/has-returns-wrong-results

Answer (score 1):

You would like to check if `"rain"` attribute is returned in the response.

To do so, follow these steps:

1. Create a class for the object in the JSON array.
2. Use Gson or any other JSON library in Android to convert the fetched JSON into the created class object.
3. Then check if rain is not null and if rain is not equal to 0 to confirm rain attribute is present in the JSON objects in the array.